# Accessing Importance of each element in Random Forest in R

Tags: r, random-forest

I have a prediction model using random forest with rolling window. In each iteration, I am saving the `importance` of the rf model into a list (let's say list1). At the end, this list (list1) includes many lists (list2) of length 1. In each of these lists (list2), I have the `importance` of one iteration. I want to access the `%IncMSE` of each element in this list (list2). For example, I want to reach lag1.mat1 `%IncMSE` which is 26.01262.

[image]

The problem is that the list (list2) is of length one, so I am not able to access the value itself.

[image]

Is there any way I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing your data looks like this:

```
library(randomForest)
lst = lapply(1:2,function(i){
list(randomForest(mpg~.,data=mtcars,importance=TRUE)$importance)
})

 str(lst)
List of 2
 $ :List of 1
  ..$ : num [1:10, 1:2] 6.921 9.651 7.495 0.984 9.178 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:10] "cyl" "disp" "hp" "drat" ...
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "%IncMSE" "IncNodePurity"
 $ :List of 1
  ..$ : num [1:10, 1:2] 7.138 10.257 7.422 0.631 10.027 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:10] "cyl" "disp" "hp" "drat" ...
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "%IncMSE" "IncNodePurity"

head(lst[[1]][[1]])
      %IncMSE IncNodePurity
cyl  6.9211021     170.12901
disp 9.6509747     248.54840
hp   7.4951588     206.99009
drat 0.9839875      64.95373
wt   9.1778411     246.08167
qsec 0.7464294      43.20173
```

If you only want cyl:

```
sapply(lst,function(x)x[[1]]["cyl","%IncMSE"])
```

If you need everything:

```
lapply(lst,function(x)x[[1]][,"%IncMSE"])
```

Comment: I have posted my code, for a better definition of how I construct the list. The thing is that with ```sapply```, I get the error of ```incorrect number of dimensions```.

Comment: I even tried adding ```h5 <- lapply(1, function(x){randomForest(y ~., data= a, mtry=5, ntree=1000, importance=TRUE)$importance})``` in the loop itself, but it returns an empty list.

Comment: ok most likely you have one more level in the list. See updated.. the code you posted is a bit hard to read...

Answer (score 0):

It would have been helpful to see at least parts of your code, but basically, you can access them by doing this:
Assuming you've grown this tree:

```
RF = purrr::accumulate( .init = update(rf_mod, ntree=1),
                          rep(1,100), randomForest::grow )
imp = purrr::map( RF, ~importance(.x)[,"%IncMSE"] )
```

From there you get the one you need in the list. For a more concise answer, post your code.